# How to pass an object to the view Spring MVC3

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, model, spring-3

I have a simple test project in Spring 3, basically a method within the controller that fetches data from an arraylist and "should" pass them to a view
Thsi is how the method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showUsers")
public String showUsers(Model model){
    ArrayList<User> users=this.copy();
    model.addAttribute(users);
    return "showUsers";
}
```

And here's the jsp (showUsers.jsp)

They both execute with no logs or warnings the view is displayed but without the `ArrayList<User>` data's :(

```
<table align="center" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Nr:</td><td>Name:</td><td>Email</td><td>Modify?</td>
    </tr> 
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${status.count}"/></td><td><c:out value="${user.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${user.email}"/></td><td>Modify</td>
        </tr>   
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Any advice?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Model documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) lists 2 methods for adding attributes to a *Model*. You are using the version without supplying a *name*, so Spring will use a [generated name](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/Conventions.html#getVariableName%28java.lang.Object%29). I think this generated name is not what you think it is.

You could add the model using `model.addAttribute("users", users);`

Comment: You mean that by calling @ModelAttribute Spring actually uses    Model addAttribute(Object attributeValue)       in stead of           Model addAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue)?

Comment: Yes, you could just use `@ModelAttribute` (the value is optional - see [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html)) but again, Spring would be creating it's own name model attribute name. However you **are** supplying the value "users", which is what is making it work.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all, i solved it this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showUsers")
@ModelAttribute("users")
public ArrayList<User> showUsers(){

    return userList;
}
```